# React Native Flatlist - Run function only when visible

Tags: react-native, fetch

I have an array with 500+ id's, each item on this array is going to fetch some data so I'm using Flatlist.

```
  <FlatList
    viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig.current}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={400}
    initialNumToRender={10}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    data={threads}
    renderItem={({item}) => <SectionThread item={item} />}
  />
```

The component SectionThread calls an api when mounted

```
  const getThread = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const o = await fetchThread(props.item);
    setThread(o);   }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getThread();   }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {thread.title}
    </View>   );
```

I need to find a way to only call this api when the item is visible, right now it calls everything at once and my app gets really laggy.

I've tried a bunch of stuff like `viewabilityConfig` but with no success.

My question is: Is there a way where the item on a flatlist is only mounted when is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was the first prop on the documentation page, windowSize fixed everything

```
  <FlatList
    disableVirtualization={true}
    windowSize={2}
    initialNumToRender={25}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    data={threads}
    renderItem={({item}) => <SectionThread item={item} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    onScrollBeginDrag={handleScroll}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={handleScroll}
  />
```

> windowSize Determines the maximum number of items rendered outside of
>   the visible area, in units of visible lengths. So if your list fills
>   the screen, then windowSize={21} (the default) will render the visible
>   screen area plus up to 10 screens above and 10 below the viewport.
>   Reducing this number will reduce memory consumption and may improve
>   performance, but will increase the chance that fast scrolling may
>   reveal momentary blank areas of unrendered content.

And for some reason the list got all crazy if I don't disable virtualization

> disableVirtualization DEPRECATED: Virtualization provides significant
>   performance and memory optimizations, but fully unmounts react
>   instances that are outside of the render window. You should only need
>   to disable this for debugging purposes.